# Neo4j counting zero relationships?

Tags: neo4j

This query won't return any users with no followers.

```
MATCH (:USER)-[f:FOLLOWS]->(u:USER)
RETURN u.name, count(f)
```

How can I return all users here along with 0 follows for the ones with no edges?

Comment: added a faster variant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match `(:User)` also when there is no `[:FOLLOWS]` you have to make the relationship optional.

```
MATCH (u:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH u-[f:FOLLOWS]->(:User)
RETURN u.name, count(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be faster:

```
MATCH (u:User)
RETURN u.name, 
       size((u)-[:FOLLOWS]->()) as following, 
       size((u)<-[:FOLLOWS]-()) as followers;
```

As it uses the getDegree function internally to retrieve the number of relationships.